# Как поместить проект из архива в среду intellij idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Допустим мне скинули папку с проектом java, там много разных файлов + классы java, как мне открыть это в среде intellij idea? для редактирования, дальнейшей работы и прочего

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для начала, проект, который упакован в архив, надо распаковать в какое то удобное место. Для *IDEA* таким местом может быть папка с проектами этой IDE назначенная ей по умолчанию. Далее:

1. Если этот проект ранее был подготовлен в среде *IntelliJ IDEA*, то просто открываете его (если в IDE открыт другой проект):

   <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Open</kbd>

То же самое можно сделать и со стартового экрана *IDEA*, когда никакой проект еще не открыт: 3-тий пункт - *Open*:[image: screen]

В появившемся окне указываете путь до корневой папки проекта.

2. Если проект подготовлен в другой IDE (написан в блокноте), его надо импортировать, чтобы *IDEA* могла создать свои рабочие файлы и каталоги:

<kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>New</kbd> -> <kbd>Project from Existing Sources ..</kbd>

На стартовом экране это второй пункт - *Import Project*

В появившемся окне необходимо указать путь до корневой папки проекта. Далее следовать указаниям мастера, так как в зависимости от того, на чем основан проект (*Maven, gradle, ant* и тд.) требуются разные действия.